# anonymous function assignment using a one line if statement

Tags: python

When assigning a variable to an anonymous function using a one line if statement, the 'else' case does not behave as expected. Instead of assigning the anonymous function listed after the 'else', a *different* anonymous function is assigned. This function returns the *expected* anonymous function.

```
>> fn = lambda x: x if True else lambda x: x*x
>> fn(2)
2
>> fn = lambda x: x if False else lambda x: x*x
>> fn(2)
<function <lambda> at 0x10086dc08>
>> fn('foo')(2)
4
```

What seems to be happening is that `lambda x: x if False else lambda x: x*x` as a whole is returned as an anonymous function in the 'else' case. I was able to achieve the desired behavior by using the following:

```
>> fn = (lambda x: x*x, lambda x: x)[True]
>> fn(2)
2
>> fn = (lambda x: x*x, lambda x: x)[False]
>> fn(2)
4
```

However, I would still like to get the bottom of this unusual behavior. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lambda` has a weaker binding than the conditional expression.  In fact, it has the least operator precedence in the language.  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

So, this line:

```
fn = lambda x: x if True else lambda x: x*x
```

is actually being interpreted by Python as:

```
fn = lambda x: (x if True else lambda x: x*x)
```

To do what you want, you would need to add parenthesis:

```
fn = (lambda x: x) if True else (lambda x: x*x)
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note that the table is ordered from least to greatest.</sub>